# VBA macros desn't work in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I use the code to copy range into email body from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm. It worked perfectly in Excel 2013, but it doesn't work in Excel 2016.

In Excel 2016 there is an error 'Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error' for this code:

```
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
```

I've no idea what is wrong. All I've found in the Internet didn't help. 
Does anybody know if there is any difference between Excel 2013 and 2016 that can affect working macros?

Answer (score 1):

Running the Excel as Administrator solves the problem in my case.

It wasn't obviously for me from the error description.

So hope it'll help someone else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I would like to suggest this Code will help u to Copy data range into mail body, it's portion of the code,, need to adjust with your code,

```
ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
    SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    Filename:=strFilename, _
    Sheet:=strWorksheetName, _
    Source:=strRangeAddress, _
    HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish True

Set objFilesytem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextstream = objFilesytem.GetFile(strFilename).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)

strTempText = objTextstream.ReadAll
objTextstream.Close

For Each objShape In Worksheets(strWorksheetName).Shapes
    If Not Intersect(objShape.TopLeftCell, Worksheets( _
        strWorksheetName).Range(strRangeAddress)) Is Nothing Then
        blnRangeContainsShapes = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next objShape
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But this code is the same and unfortunately the problem is still open

Comment: Feeling sorry, the code is not working,, possibly it may be problem related to the privilege,,,!